# Looking for a specific presentation template

Tags: templates, presentations

Can somebody help me to find this template:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the default style for the `prosper` class, one of the older classes for presentations. The documentation, in `…texmf-dist/doc/latex/prosper`, includes example `.tex` files for the default and for eleven other styles, some of them quite attractive. It’s also possible, and not too difficult, to make your own styles, and there are additional styles, without examples, in `…texmf-dist/tex/latex/prosper`.

The examples should be compiled with `latex` (not `pdflatex` or `lualatex` or `xelatex`), and the resulting `.dvi` file converted to `.ps` and then possibly to `.pdf`.

If you like `prosper`, you should also look at `HA-prosper`, which added some fixes, and at `powerdot`, the successor to `HA-prosper`.